# React add script JS to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, components

I try to add a JS script to an React component, nevertheless nothing append.
The message Hello is displayed but not the script.
The swcript is to the same repository that the component Canvas.
I try to add it like this:

```
class Accueil extends Component {

render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <Canvas/>
    </div>
    );
}
```

}

```
class Canvas extends Component {
componentDidMount() {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
      script.async = true;
      script.src = "./Sketch.js";
      this.div.appendChild(script);
      }

render() {
  return (
    <div className="App" ref={el => (this.div = el)}> 
    <h1>Hello</h1>
      {/* Script is inserted here */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

}

But when I insert directly the script Sketch in top of the page
import {Sketch} from './Sketch.js'

The script is well add but it is add also for other components, so I think it is not the well way to do it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

If you dynamically append a script to body or anything inside body, it will not get executed (because everything there executes only once during page load. You have to append it to head.

You can use global variables help it 'find its component' or vice versa...

Comment: Thank you for your return, do you have an exemple of that ? because the problem is when I append it to head, the script is append for all the component, no matter what if the script is present or not, and that is my problem too

Comment: A lot depends on what the script does. Your component can set a global variable (variable = myId;). Then when the script runs it finds the I'd and locates the component with it. You can still try other options; but those are more complex...